# EmberJS: issue with a custom template helper and its dependencies

Tags: ember.js

I have defined a custom template helper similar to what they show [in the Ember guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/writing-helpers/).

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('fullName', function(person) {
  return person.get('firstName') + ' ' + person.get('lastName');
}, 'firstName', 'lastName');
```

Yet, every time I load the page, I get a strange error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
```

I tried to track it down, and I wonder if it could be a context issue. Indeed, when I break in Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper, I can see that the observers that it is trying to register for 'firstName' and 'lastName' do not have a proper path. They are ".firstName" and ".lastName" which does not mean anything...

Do you have any idea what might be happening?

Also, I should add: if I remove the dependencies:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('fullName', function(person) {
  return person.get('firstName') + ' ' + person.get('lastName');
});
```

I can break in my helper. When I do person.toString(), it seems "normal" (with the right ID, etc), yet, when I do person.get('firstName') in the console I get null, as if the record had not completely loaded. Strange.

Thanks

PJ

Comment: Putting up a simple fiddle would make finding the bug much easier.

Comment: I know, and I always do provide one... but I am struggling to reproduce here. It happens fairly "deep" in the app (with many relationships between the objects). I was just hoping to get directions on what might be wrong instead of a definite answer.

Comment: Sorry, but in this case no one can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug is a bug (https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2948) I provided fix for this: https://github.com/seeweer/ember.js/commit/0226e1c605f84e469e56c7c397599a4295946094

This bug was caused by `this` on handlebar helper.
For example if you have such template:

```
{{someHelper this}}
```

Then instead of `this` you can use for example `view.context` if you are in the view or `controller` if you are in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps other people: it was a context issue. It is a bit weird since "person" within the helper was indeed an App.Person. But I tried various context shifts and it ended up working (it might be because I am on master?). So in case you hit a strange behaviour like this, you might want to double check what context you are passing to the helper.